# How to change css of the hover text in mat-icon angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am using a mat-icon like this

*HTML CODE* file - datentry.component.html

```
<mat-icon 
      matTooltip="Time limit exceeded for current sku" 
      matTooltipPosition="above" 
      matTooltipClass="delay-msg-tooltip">
      info
</mat-icon>
```

I want to change the background color and font color for the hover text "Time limit exceeded for current SKU", I have tried like this without any success.

*CSS CODE* file dataentry-component.scss

```
.delay-msg-tooltip {
  background-color: #FFFFFF!important;
  color: #5F5F5F!important;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 23px #0000000d!important;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

For reference in the browser, the mat-icon HTML shows up like this

```
<mat-icon _ngcontent-nph-c79="" role="img" mattooltip="Time limit exceeded for current sku" mattooltipposition="above" mattooltipclass="delay-msg-tooltip" class="mat-icon notranslate mat-tooltip-trigger material-icons mat-icon-no-color ng-star-inserted" aria-hidden="true" data-mat-icon-type="font" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-0" cdk-describedby-host=""> info </mat-icon>
```

Images for reference
curr view

[image: curr view]

desired view

[image: desired view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where have you written the CSS for `.delay-msg-tooltip`?

Because of Angular View Encapsulation you'll need to write the styling in your `styles.scss` and not the component's style

Comment: I have updated the file names above

Comment: Move the styling for the .delay-msg-tooltip to your styles.scss and you should be good. Just keep in mind that this will apply the style globally to any tooltip with that class

Comment: Do you know how can I add a img inside the text like that in the desired image I have added above?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Material Icon Documentation

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tooltip-custom-class-example',
  templateUrl: 'tooltip-custom-class-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['tooltip-custom-class-example.css'],
  // Need to remove view encapsulation so that the custom tooltip style defined in
  // `tooltip-custom-class-example.css` will not be scoped to this component's view.
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

You'll either have to set `ViewEncapsulation` to `None` so that the styling you applied in your component is applied to the matToolTip as the ToolTip is not technically inside your component.
Or

You can add the styles in the `styles.css` so that they are applied globally.

I recommend doing the latter. As it saves me from changing the view encapsulation of the component and keep the styles encapsulated of that component